# red 5 - connecting via rtmpt issues

Tags: streaming, red5, rtmp

I have a red 5 server up and running successfully using regular rtmpt.
I have also made the necessary changes as per this [link](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/red5-server-rtmpt-with-apache-as-webserver-and-flowplayer-configuration/)

Watching the logs of a typical working connection to red5 via RTMP. I see the following.

```
==> /var/log/red5/error.log <==
2011-12-12 10:48:41,261 [http-8088-exec-2] ERROR o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Unable to validate client

==> /var/log/red5/red5.log <==
2011-12-12 10:48:41,261 [http-8088-exec-2] ERROR o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Unable to validate client
2011-12-12 10:48:41,484 [http-8088-exec-3] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
2011-12-12 10:48:41,492 [http-8088-exec-3] INFO  o.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [WebScope@df8b14 Depth = 1, Path = '/default', Name = 'splitstream']
2011-12-12 10:48:41,731 [http-8088-exec-4] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action authorize1
2011-12-12 10:48:41,971 [http-8088-exec-5] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action authorize2
2011-12-12 10:48:42,200 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action releaseStream
2011-12-12 10:48:42,200 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action FCPublish
2011-12-12 10:48:42,202 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action createStream
2011-12-12 10:48:42,432 [http-8088-exec-2] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action publish
2011-12-12 10:48:42,440 [http-8088-exec-2] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider connect
2011-12-12 10:48:42,441 [http-8088-exec-2] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Stream start
2011-12-12 10:48:42,442 [http-8088-exec-2] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Provider connect
2011-12-12 10:48:43,118 [http-8088-exec-5] INFO  o.r.s.stream.codec.ScreenVideo2 - Allocating memory for 510 compressed blocks
```

When I switch to RTMPT I don't seem to see the Provider connect, Stream Start messages - and of course my stream never starts.

```
==> /var/log/red5/error.log <==
2011-12-12 10:57:52,177 [http-8088-exec-2] ERROR o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Unable to validate client

==> /var/log/red5/red5.log <==
2011-12-12 10:57:52,177 [http-8088-exec-2] ERROR o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Unable to validate client
2011-12-12 10:57:52,405 [http-8088-exec-3] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
2011-12-12 10:57:52,411 [http-8088-exec-3] INFO  o.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [WebScope@db38a4 Depth = 1, Path = '/default', Name = 'splitstream']
2011-12-12 10:57:52,613 [http-8088-exec-4] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action authorize1
2011-12-12 10:57:52,847 [http-8088-exec-5] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action authorize2
2011-12-12 10:57:53,079 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action releaseStream
2011-12-12 10:57:53,079 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action FCPublish
2011-12-12 10:57:53,079 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action createStream
2011-12-12 10:57:53,316 [http-8088-exec-2] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action publish
```

I also notice this in my logs

```
2011-12-13 04:54:00,980 [http-8088-exec-2] INFO  o.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope :80/splitstream not found on dev-100.host.com:80:80

==> /var/log/red5/error.log <==
2011-12-13 04:54:05,105 [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-1] WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPTConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 47814 to localhost.localdomain (in: 3626 out 3265 ), with id 6 due to long handshake

==> /var/log/red5/red5.log <==
2011-12-13 04:54:05,105 [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-1] WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPTConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 47814 to localhost.localdomain (in: 3626 out 3265 ), with id 6 due to long handshake
2011-12-13 04:54:06,402 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.r.s.n.r.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
2011-12-13 04:54:06,403 [http-8088-exec-1] INFO  o.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [WebScope@19c6163 Depth = 1, Path = '/default', Name = 'splitstream']
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of `rtmpt.max_inactivity` in the `red5.properties` file. Also change the value of `maxHandshakeTimeout` in the `rtmpt` section of `red5-core.xml` file and retry.